# Trying to send information through a form in Java/Spring with MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this little app, so far just have gotten some work done on the login page, but I am trying to send the username and password to a controller method, and I don't think I am doing it correctly.  I have tried testing the connection to the database, and it seems to be fine, and it seems to be grabbing the info out of the database fine, but testing the info from the form has been giving me null values.  I am convinced the problem is in either this controller method:

```
`@RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView displayform()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("login", "userobj", new User());
    }

or this form:

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Subari Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form action="LoginResult" method="post" modelAttribute="userobj">
<h1 style="color: red;">Welcome to Subari!!</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /><input style="float: right;" type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form:form>

</body>
</html>`
```

Here is the complete controller file:

`````
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.example.demo.model.User;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet usernameResults = null;
    ResultSet passwordResults = null;
    
    
    public LoginController(){       
        
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView displayform()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("login", "userobj", new User());
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/LoginResult")
    public ModelAndView retrieveData(@ModelAttribute("userobj") User u)
    {   
        
        boolean userFound = false;
        boolean passwordMatch = false;
        
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hiberprj", "root", "bdiver1");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT username, password FROM user";
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            
         
            
            while(results.next()) {
                String username = results.getString("username");
                String password = results.getString("password");
                
                System.out.println(username);
                
                if (u.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                    userFound = true;
                    if (u.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                        passwordMatch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if (userFound && passwordMatch) {
                return new ModelAndView("success", "username", u.getUsername());
            } else if (userFound) {
                return new ModelAndView("loginError", "error", "Invalid password");
            } else {
                return new ModelAndView("loginError", "error", "User not found");
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        return new ModelAndView("loginError", "error", "some other error");
    }
    }

     
        
        
    //      try {
    //          Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    //          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hiberprj",   "root", "bdiver1");
            
    //          if(con == null)
    //          {
    //              System.out.println("database not connected");
    //          }
    //          else
    //          {
    //              System.out.println("database connected!!!");
    //          }
            
    //          stmt = con.createStatement();
    //          String usernames = "SELECT username FROM USER";
    //          String passwords = "SELECT password FROM USER";
            
    //          String query = "SELECT username, password FROM user";
    //            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            
    //          usernameResults = stmt.executeQuery(usernames);
    //          passwordResults = stmt.executeQuery(passwords);
            
            //System.out.println("Inside try");
            
    //          System.out.println(results.next());
    //          
    //          while(results.next())
    //          {
    //              System.out.println("Inside while");
    //              String username = results.getString(0);
    //                  if(u.getUsername().equals(username))
    //                  {
    //                      passwordResults.next();
    //                      String password = results.getString(1);
    //                      if(u.getPassword().equals(password)) {
    //                          return new ModelAndView("success", username", u.getUsername());
    //                      }
    //                  }
    //          }
    //      }
    //      catch(SQLException e)
    //      {
    //          e.printStackTrace();
    //          return new ModelAndView("loginError", "error", "database error");
    //      }
    //      catch(Exception e)
    //      {
    //          return new ModelAndView("loginError", "error", "database error");
    //      }
    //      
    //      return new ModelAndView("success", "yay", "hooray");````

    In the retrieveData method, u.getUsername() and u.getPassword() ae both coming in as null.
    
    here is the User class:

```
`package com.example.demo.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="Userid")
    private int userid;
    
    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="Username")
    public String username;
    
    @Column(name="Password")
    public String password;
    
    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    private void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    private void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}`

```
here is the UserRepository:

```
`import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.model.User;

/*
 * Spring boot is containing jpaRepository,which can be used for database 
 * operations. 
 * CrudRepository interface contains the method for basic Crud operations
 * JpaRepsotiory is extending from CrudRepository which contains additonal 
 * features like pagination and sorting
 */
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {

}`
```

here is the pom.xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mydemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>SubariSpring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SubariSpring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    </project>`
```

    Any help is greatly appreciated!!


    Have tested the database connection in the retrieveData method, and the connection and        retrieving the username and password out of it have come back fine.  Have tested the username and  password coming from the form contents and they are not coming back fine.  Both are coming back null, so I truly believe the problem is in there somewhere.
`````